# HTML5 & XML in PhoneGap Iphone

Tags: iphone, xml, web-services, html, cordova

Let said currently I want to pull a XML file from a server which include name, text, video, image & etc. Can HTML 5 directly read the XML and put it into the html body or I can only use JavaScript to pull the information. Will it be the same in the iPhone when using PhoneGap to develop?

Thank in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your going to have to use Javascript, whether or not you are developing on Phonegap or not.

Comment: Now the case, I want to develop a iPhone web apps to run the Web Services to do data processing, transaction, video streaming, login, or what ever, the only option I have is need to use JavaScript to call the web services?

I mean HTML5 don't have any native handler or control on the web services right?

Comment: HTML5 is not a language, it is a way of describing text and graphics.  All processing must be done with either client side javascript with possible interaction with Web Services.  All that Phonegap gives you is access (through javascript) to some native services on the iphone.